# Reverse Langlands transform

Tags: geometric-langlands, ag.algebraic-geometry

What os the meaning of `a reverse Langlands transform` to which Drinfeld [seems to refer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2464/what-is-drinfelds-manuscript-best-dream-in-russian-about)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that, traditionally, the Geometric Langlands program seems to be looking for a functor from D_{coh}(Loc,O)\to D_{coh}(^L Bun,D), that is, from the derived category on the space of local systems to the derived category of D-modules on the space of bundles for the Langlands dual.  So, by reverse Langlands transformation, he might be asking for a functor in the other direction, to try to establish the equivalence.